# How can i filter a list in excel to a specific number and also have the sum not to exceed a certain number

Tags: excel

I was wondering if there is a way in excel to get to specific list count (top 150) but at the same time, try and get the total sum not to exceed a certain limit (45,000)

Many thanks

Comment: `result = MIN(SUM(......), 45000)` or something like that.

Comment: So, have a column that can be binary, then use sumproduct() and the Solver. Count() for 150 and sum()<=45000

Comment: Do you have sample data?

Comment: Yes I have a sample data

Comment: Where is it? ..

Comment: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AuGQv-JcFO2ZgS681Nz5MHNbPMq3?e=Ghrwt0

Comment: in the "included for promotion" tab, i want to get a list of 150 diamonds, but the 10% percent discount should not exceed 45k